# Get last executed command in bash

Tags: bash, prompt, built-in

I need to know what was the last command executed while setting my bash prompt in the function corresponding to PROMPT_COMMAND. I have code as follows

```
function bash_prompt_command () { 
...
    local last_cmd="$(history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1  | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3-)"
    [[ ${last_cmd} =~ .*git\s+checkout.* ]] && ( ... )
...
}
```

Is there is faster(bash built-in way) to know the what was the  command which invoked PROMPT_COMMAND.
I tried using BASH_COMMAND, but that too does not return the command which actually invoked PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way.  What issues do you have with your code?  What else would you want it to do?

Comment: You can certainly create a DEBUG trap that stores the commands it's asked whether to permit execution of, much more efficiently than what you're trying here.

Comment: if current(last) command is git checkout, i want to set PS1 in certain way.

Comment: @hardeep, have you considered just creating a function to shadow `git` and modify behavior when running `checkout`?

Comment: BTW, `function funcname() {` merges the ksh syntax `function funcname {` and the POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` in a way that's incompatible with _both_ ksh and POSIX. Pick one or the other (the POSIX one if you care about portability), don't merge both together -- see also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: I can try shadow git but since git is used by several other bash completion functions, it will be tricky.

Comment: Not tricky at all. I've shown how to do it in other Q&A entries.

Comment: ok, i will try..thx

Comment: @hardeep : From a practical viewpoint: Why do you want to show a different prompt after a `git checkout`? Wouldn't it make more sense to **always** show the current git branch, if the working directory happens to be within a git repositiory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### General case: Collecting *all* commands

You can use a `DEBUG` trap to store each command before it's run.

```
store_command() {
  declare -g last_command current_command
  last_command=$current_command
  current_command=$BASH_COMMAND
  return 0
}
trap store_command DEBUG
```

...and thereafter you can check `"$last_command"`

---

#### Special case: Only trying to shadow one (sub)command

If you only want to change how one command operates, you can just shadow that one command. For `git checkout`:

```
git() {
  # if $1 is not checkout, just run real git and pretend we weren't here
  [[ $1 = checkout ]] || { command git "$@"; return; }
  # if $1 _is_ checkout, run real git and do our own thing
  local rc=0
  command git "$@" || rc=$?
  ran_checkout=1 # ...put the extra code you want to run here...
  return "$rc"
}
```

...potentially used from something like:

```
bash_prompt_command() {
  if (( ran_checkout )); then
    ran_checkout=0
    : "do special thing here"
  else
    : "do other thing here"
  fi
}
```