# How to change the terminal title to currently running process?

Tags: bash, windows-terminal

I know [how to change the Terminal Window title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title).  What I am trying to find out is how to make `bash` not `zsh` write out the currently running process so if I say do

```
$ ls -lF
```

I would get something like this for the title

```
/home/me/curerntFolder (ls -lF)
```

[Getting the last executed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624234/get-last-executed-command-in-bash) would be too late since the command has executed already, so it won't set the title with the command that was executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: my previous answer (below) displays the *previous* command in the title bar.

Ignoring everything from my previous answer and starting from scratch:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD}: (${BASH_COMMAND})\007"' DEBUG
```

Running the following at the command prompt:

```
$ sleep 10
```

The window title bar changes to `/my/current/directory: (sleep 10)` *while* the `sleep 10` is running.

Running either of these:

```
$ sleep 1; sleep 2; sleep 3
$ { sleep 1; sleep2; sleep 3; }
```

The title bar changes as each `sleep` command is invoked.

Running this:

```
$ ( sleep 1; sleep 2; sleep 3 )
```

The title bar does not change (the `trap` does not apply within a subprocess call).

One last one:

```
$ echo $(sleep 3; echo abc)
```

The title bar displays `(echo $sleep 3; echo abc))`.

---

**previous answer**

Adding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69624336):

```
store_command() {
  declare -g last_command current_command
  last_command=$current_command
  current_command=$BASH_COMMAND
  return 0
}
trap store_command DEBUG

PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD}: (${last_command})\007"'
```

---

Additional reading materials re: `trap / DEBUG`:

- [bash guide on traps](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)
- [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51557238)

Comment: can you add a note what the `trap DEBUG` does?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @markp-fuso's answer, here's how I did it to make it work with Starship.

```sh
  function set_win_title() {
    local cmd=" ($@)"
    if [[ "$cmd" == " (starship_precmd)" || "$cmd" == " ()" ]]
    then
      cmd=""
    fi
    if [[ $PWD == $HOME ]]
    then
      if [[ $SSH_TTY ]]
      then
        echo -ne "\033]0; ️ @ $HOSTNAME ~$cmd\a" < /dev/null
      else
        echo -ne "\033]0;  ~$cmd\a" < /dev/null
      fi
    else
      BASEPWD=$(basename "$PWD")
      if [[ $SSH_TTY ]]
      then
        echo -ne "\033]0; ️ $BASEPWD @ $HOSTNAME $cmd\a" < /dev/null
      else
        echo -ne "\033]0;  $BASEPWD $cmd\a" < /dev/null
      fi
    fi

  }
  starship_precmd_user_func="set_win_title"
  eval "$(starship init bash)"
  trap "$(trap -p DEBUG |  awk -F"'" '{print $2}');set_win_title \${BASH_COMMAND}" DEBUG
```

Note this differs from the [Custom pre-prompt and pre-execution Commands in Bash instructions](https://starship.rs/advanced-config/#custom-pre-prompt-and-pre-execution-commands-in-bash) in that the trap is set *after* `starship init`.  Which I have noted in [a bug](https://github.com/starship/starship/issues/3749).

Comment: PS: to get nice colorful emojis, make sure to have a fallback font like "Noto Color Emoji" installed.

Comment: Right now starship documentation recommends to use `precmd_functions+=(set_win_title)` instead of a trap: https://starship.rs/advanced-config/#change-window-title

Answer (score 2):

For **Linux OS** Adding following function in **bashrc** file

**Following Steps**

1. Open bashrc file

> vi ~/.bashrc

2. Write a function in bashrc file

   ```
   function set-title() {
      if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
        ORIG=$PS1
      fi
      TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
      PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
    }
   ```

[image]

3. save the file

> source ~/.bashrc

4. call function

> set-title "tab1"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine setting the window title with setting the prompt.

Here's an example using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)s `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```sh
tputps () {
    echo -n '\['
    tput "$@"
    echo -n '\]'
}

prompt_builder () {
    # Window title - operating system command (OSC) ESC + ]
    echo -ne '\033]0;'"${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$(dirs)"'\a' >&2

    # username, green
    tputps setaf 2
    echo -n '\u'

    # directory, orange
    tputps setaf 208
    echo -n ' \w'
    tputps sgr0 0
}

prompt_cmd () {
    PS1="$(prompt_builder) \$ "
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was unable to find anywhere some instructions about avoiding the use of raw escape sequences to set the title of a terminal emulator window.  Using obscure raw escape sequences isn't great and is one of the reasons why the [terminfo database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) was created, so I got motivated to research it all in detail, to implement setting the window title properly in my `~/.bashrc`, and to finally write this answer.

First, here's an excerpt from my `~/.bashrc`, which shows the `bash` code I implemented to set the window title, while using no raw escape sequences:

```bash
if [[ "${TERM}" != 'linux' ]]; then
        # Force the terminal type, to work around GUI terminal
        # emulators that set $TERM wrongly to a type that doesn't
        # support status line, e.g. "xterm-256color"

        SL_TERM='xterm-pcolor'
        SL_START="$(TERM=${SL_TERM}; tput tsl)"
        SL_END="$(TERM=${SL_TERM}; tput fsl)"

        SL_CMD='${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*} ${PWD/#${HOME}/\~}'
        SL_CMD+='$(STATUS=${?}; [[ ${STATUS} != 0 ]] && echo -n " [ERROR: ${STATUS}]")'

        PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n \"${SL_START}${SL_CMD}${SL_END}\""
        unset SL_TERM SL_START SL_END SL_CMD
else
        unset PROMPT_COMMAND
fi
```

The key here is to use the [`tput(1)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tput.1.en) utility to generate the required escape sequences, using the [`terminfo(5)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/terminfo.5.en) database that describes the capabilities of various terminals and terminal emulators.  As you can see in the comment in the `bash` code above, some terminal emulators actually misbehave a bit, but that can be worked around rather easily.

The two terminal capabilities we're interested in are `tsl` (`to_status_line`, move to status line, column #1) and `fsl` (`from_status_line`, return from status line).  These two capabilities actually produce the raw escape sequences `\033]0;` and `\007`, respectively, which you can find mentioned everywhere.

Obviously, the Linux virtual console has no status line capabilities, so the code above configures no status line updates when the shell is running there.  The capabilities of each terminal type can be checked rather easily by using [`infocmp(1M)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/infocmp.1m), for example by running `infocmp -I linux`, `infocmp -I xterm-256color`, or `infocmp -I xterm-pcolor`.

Here are also a few versions of the *XTerm Control Sequences* reference, which are rather hard to locate, listed in the descending order of their readability: [2023 version](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (HTML), [1994 version](https://www.x.org/docs/xterm/ctlseqs.pdf) (PDF), and [2005 version](https://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html) (HTML).

I hope this will help with demystifying the whole thing a bit.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to change the title of the terminal I could think of is to use echo in shell script

```
echo "\033]0;Your title \007"
```

And to change open a new tab with new title name is

```
meta-terminal--tab-t"Your title"
```